# Loading users profile images who have "posted" a post onto a table view

Tags: swift, firebase, imageview, firebase-storage

So I have a similar app to twitter, and I would like to have it so when a user posts a "tweet", their profile picture is next to the post. The current code i have now just retrieves the user who is currently logged in and shows their profile picture in the image view, however I would like it to have the picture of the user that posted.

```
func imageLoaded() {

        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        database.child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                self.emailLbl.text = dict["users"] as? String
                if let imageViewURL = dict["pic"] as? String{
                    let url = URL(string: imageViewURL)
                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error!)
                            return
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.profileImage?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        }
                    }).resume()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you would need to get the posting user’s UID. Then the code you have above could be used to get their details and image. In your app, does a post include the poster’s UID? Is it protected by the authentication?

Comment: What's preventing you from storing the users picture who made the post (as small thumbnail) within your /users node or even the /posts node so you can load it with the post? You could even store a large, full size pic in Firebase Storage if you prefer.

Comment: I tried sending the "pic" of with the post function however it never gets sent off and the app crashes, I have made sure the user has . profile pic before sending a post off. here is my code                                
 func uploadPost(withMessage messsge: String, forUID uid: String, withPic pic: URL, withGroupKey groupKey: String?, sendComplete: @escaping (_ status: Bool) -> ()){
        if groupKey != nil {
        } else {
            feed.childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["content": messsge, "senderId": uid, "pic": pic] )
            sendComplete(true)
        }
        
    }

Comment: Please don't include code in comments - it's darn near impossible to read. One option is to encode the pic into a string and store it in the /users/uid node. Then, as you are retrieving the posters information for each post, their name, post count etc, you can also retrieve their pic. There are other ways of tackling it as well but please update your question so we can attempt to formulate and answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce the MVC pattern. This is near enough impossible to do or maintain without doing this. You need to create a Post object that'll hold all the information about that post(s) so when you want to display it, you just load that Post into your table view and display everything in that cell. Here's a brilliant tutorial covering it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qD582zfXlgo&index=4&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JEfHqwjBV0XFb9qx9cGXwkq